# SQL - Multiple conditions where clause the same column

Tags: sql

I have a dataset that looks a little something like this

```
Subject_ID   Diagnosis_ID  
001          299
001          288
001          233
001          299
002          299
002          233
003          238
004          299
004          233
```

I'd like to create a new new table consisting of patients that have 
diagnosis codes 299 and 233.

The code tried so far has been

```
Select *
  From mytable 
 where diagnosis_id = 299 AND diagnosis_id=233
```

This hasn't worked -

I've also tried

```
Select *
  From mytable 
 where diagnosis_id = 299 
INTERSECT
Select *
From mytable 
where diagnosis_id= 233
```

This hasn't worked either.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There is one thing that you didn't left clear. You need BOTH diagnosis for the patient of at least one?

Comment: I think you probably want an `OR` instead of an `AND`. By the same logic, you probably want an `UNION` instead of `INTERSECT`

Comment: And BTW, in some databases you can do the INSERT directly with a syntax like `INSERT INTO table_with_new_values(field1, field2) SELECT ...`

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly 

Yes i need the results to show patient_id's who have both diagnosis codes present :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  Subject_ID from (
     Select Distinct Subject_ID, Diagnosis_ID
       From
       Table_1
       Where Diagnosis_ID=299 or Diagnosis_ID=288
)
Group By Subject_ID
Having count(Subject_ID)>=2
```

Comment: nice, it is complete

Answer (score 3):

Think `group by` and `having`:

```
Select patient_id
From mytable
where diagnosis_id in (299, 233)
group by patient_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  If your table can have duplicates, then use `count(distinct diagnosis_id) = 2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response 

The code
 "having count(*) = 2 " 

would that mean it would only produce patients that have both diagnosis codes? (thats exactly what i want / badly need :P)

Comment: @willepi . . . That is exactly what that does.

Answer (score 2):

you can use IN()...   .

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE diagnosis_id IN(233, 299);
```

Comment: I know about that..! Thanks for comment
BETWEEN 233 AND 299 will show every diagnose_id that is between them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response :)

I tried the in statement - but this seems to be akin to OR . 

What I want is for the results to show me only patients that have both diagnosis codes  :)

Comment: If you use DISTINCT subject_ID   instead of * from the above code..

--> IT will definitely display the one with both diagnose id..!

Comment: result will be 1,2,4  subject_ID

Answer (score 1):

Check this:-

```
Select subject_id 
from
(
Select distinct subject_id, diagnosis_id
from
mytable
where diagnosis_id in ('299','233')
) a
group by subject_id
having count(*)=2
```

Thanks:-)

Comment: Thank you for your help - could I ask what the "a" after the where statment does exactly :)

Comment: @willepi In sql an sub query fetching columns from some other table is like a new table. 'a' here just gives an alias to this table which is getting generated in inner query. In short, an alias for a sub query tells sql to identify it as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can use this :

```
Select *
  From mytable 
 where (diagnosis_id = 299 or diagnosis_id=233)
```