# SQL - Different conditions on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I'm trying to achieve something very similar to [SQL - Multiple conditions where clause the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563550/sql-multiple-conditions-where-clause-the-same-column)

The difference is that I want two separate WHERE conditions:

```
 WHERE tag_id IN (1,2)
 OR tag_id IN (3,2)
 GROUP BY other_id HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = 2
```

This gives me all the records that I need, but also gives me records that have the tags 1 or 3 even when that record doesn't have `tag_id = 2`. I know that my problem is in the `OR` condition, because if I do `(1,2)` and `(3,2)` separately, I get the expected results for each query.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post a data sample + desired output (as text)

Comment: Does `(tag_id, other_id)` is defined as unique by according index? if not then you must take into account that duplicated rows are theoretically possible (and they will occur somewhere in future, close to with guarantee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT other_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY other_id
HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = 2 AND              -- 2 tags
       (SUM(tag_id NOT IN (1, 2)) = 0 OR  -- either (1, 2)
        SUM(tag_id NOT IN (3, 2)) = 0);   -- or (3, 2)
```